# How to display the tables on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to display tables on particular locations on Google Maps.
Suppose, if I have 3 locations a,b,c. Now I want to do the following :
1. Create markers in the three locations
2. When I move over this markers, I should get a table with rows and columns of that location.
   The table should fetch the data from database and display the data. Ex: No of employees and their presence on that day.

How can I do this using Google Maps. Can anyone guide on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add an infowindow to a marker click event. Inside the infowindow you will draw the table passing the HTML as the content. The tricky part is the data. You can either load all the data when you load the page and show it when the marker is clicked or get it on demand with an ajax request. I will go with the second if the data is big.

Comment: I want to display the data from database which has only one table. But, I'm new to this concept, can you provide some references for this..